# How to set spellfile with spaces

Tags: spell-checking

I am trying to give vim a global spellfile and a project-specific spellfile. The project-specific file is `./en.utf-8.add` relative to the cwd. This works fine if the project directory has no spaces, but gives error `E474: Invalid argument` when calling `set spellfile+=` for a path with spaces. I tried escaping the path with `fnameescape()`, but I still get the error. Surrounding the path in quotes does not give any error, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I know I can just put the basename of the spell file relative to cwd, but I want entries in `spellfile` to be absolute. Mostly because I want to be able to programmatically find the index of the local `spellfile` for `[count]zg` and `[count]zug`.

#### Edit: Add examples

```
set spellfile=/foo bar/en.utf-8.add -> E474: Invalid argument: spellfile=/foo
set spellfile=/foo\ bar/en.utf-8.add -> E474: Invalid argument: spellfile=/foo\ bar/en.utf-8.add
set spellfile=/foo\\ bar/en.utf-8.add -> E474: Invalid argument: spellfile=/foo\\
set spellfile=/foobar/en.utf-8.add -> Sets the spellfile to /foobar/en.utf-8.add as expected
```

Interestingly, it seems that with a single space, the whole path is accepted, but somehow still invalid. With 0 or 2 spaces, the input is chopped when the space is reached, which makes sense. So, I can correctly encode the space, but it's still invalid for a `spellfile`?

Comment: `:help :set-args` and `:help option-backslash`

Comment: Also `:help-&` if this is happening programmatically.

Comment: According to `option-backslash`, a single backslash before each space should suffice. "To include white space in a string option value it has to be preceded with a
backslash.  To include a backslash you have to use two." If I want a space, I put a backslash before. I don't want a backslash in the result, so I don't put 2.

Comment: Anyway, I tried it with 1, 2, 4, and 8 backslashes before each space and still no luck. Removing the space from the path removes the error. Tried in vim and nvim.

Comment: it might help if you [edit] with specific examples.

Comment: I added some, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You say this should be relative to the current directory... Did you try something like `let &spellfile = fnamemodify('en.utf-8.add', ':p')` ? That should set it to the `en.utf-8.add` file in the current directory, using an absolute path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This has been [fixed](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b2620202c7778d8c709941fb430eeeeab6e63a6a) in version 8.2.1926.

Looking at the source code for Vim, it seems Vim will [try to validate the spell file name](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/spell.c#L4314,L4326) and it will only consider characters in [`'isfname'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27) as valid.

As a workaround, you can add a space to `'isfname'` (perhaps temporarily) in order to set `'spellfile'` to a name containing a space:

```
set isfname+=32
set spellfile=/foo\ bar/en.utf-8.add
set isfname-=32
```

Note that 32 is the ASCII code for a space character. See `:help 'isfname'` for more details on how that option works.

Comment: Filed a bug about it: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7230

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. One note: maybe it would be more explicit to use `char2nr(' ')`?

Comment: @Marcel The problem with using a function such as `char2nr()` is that `:set` doesn't evaluate functions, so you need to use `:let &isfname` but it's hard to do so when appending a value (as in `:set spellfile+=...`) or use `:execute`. In any case, I'm hoping the bug will be taken care upstream, it clearly looks like a bug to me, I don't know anywhere else where path names are checked for validity using the `'isfname'` setting, that's mostly to identify paths inside a buffer's contents.

Comment: It is a bit more challenging, yes. Here is what I decided on: `let l:prev_isfname = &isfname
execute 'set isfname+=' . char2nr(' ')
execute 'set spellfile+=' . fnameescape(g:local_spellfile_path)
let &isfname = l:prev_isfname
`